# What are the basis vectors of the cone of positive semi definite matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, semidefinite-programming

**I was wondering if we could find a set of basis vectors that span the cone of positive semidefinite matrices?**

I know this question is hard, but I would really appreciate if even someone can share a related paper about this topic in the literature of Linear Algebra. I could not find any paper about this issue. I should mention that any answer to this question should be highly related to the topic of semidefinite programming in the area of mathematical optimization.

Thanks

Comment: Related (only instead of "interior" boundaries are included for semi-definite): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1743879/existence-of-a-basis-for-the-symmetric-positive-definite-matrices